# Can you target yourself with ranged touch attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you target yourself with ranged touch attack?
Currently have a Damphir Magus Lv11 and I wonder can use Glooming Bolt on myself to heal me in dire situation since Negative energy heals me? are there lower level spells that deal negative energy that can use?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoLI9FHmV90)

Comment: What kind of a GM says *no* when a player asks, "Can my PC shoot himself in the face?"

Comment: Just remember to roll reflex to not blind yourself ;)

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, you can

From [Range](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#range) on spells:

> **Range**
>
> A spell's range indicates how far from you it can reach, as defined in the range entry of the spell description. **A spell's range is the maximum distance** from you that the spell's effect can occur, as well as the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell's point of origin. If any portion of the spell's area would extend beyond this range, that area is wasted.

[Glooming Bolt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gloomblind-bolts/) says:

> Range medium (100 ft. + 10 ft./level)

And finally, nothing on the description of [Rays](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#aiming-a-spell) suggests you cannot target yourself. On the contrary, it says it works as firing a ranged weapon. And thus, it follows the more general rules of targeting and range.

> Ray: Some effects are rays. **You aim a ray as if using a ranged weapon**, though typically you make a ranged touch attack rather than a normal ranged attack. As with a ranged weapon, you can fire into the dark or at an invisible creature and hope you hit something. You don't have to see the creature you're trying to hit, as you do with a targeted spell. Intervening creatures and obstacles, however, can block your line of sight or provide cover for the creature at which you're aiming.

The [Reach Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/reach-spell-metamagic/) metamagic could be used to increase a [Cure Light Wounds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds) range from touch to short, but you still should be able to heal yourself using that spell.

This means you are a completely valid target for [shooting yourself in the face](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMIBeU1gDuc). Unless the spell has an exception, such as [targeting only objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinetic-volley/) or [only your enemies](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/).

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific rules for attacking yourself.  So, RAW says no.

However, I agree with @HeyICanChan.

> What kind of a GM says no when a player asks, "Can my PC shoot himself
>   in the face?" – @HeyICanChan

Also, previous DnD versions have stated that you auto-hit yourself and I agree with that.

As a GM, I'd allow you to "shoot yourself in the foot" since it doesn't contradict the rules in either letter or spirit.

If you were running and jumping at the time (or dodging sword blows), I might make you make a ranged touch attack though.